# Inner class not able to access outer class member variable which is initialized from a method which internally calls constructor

Tags: java, inner-classes, synchronized

Below code throwing nullpointer Exception due to uninitialized outer member variable.
it is throwing NPE in run method for runnable variable. I have initialized local valiable of type ConcurrentLinkedQueue in newFixedThreadPool method and called parameterized constructor to initialized the runnable member variable.

BTW when I directly initialize the runnable variable without creating any local variable code runs successfully.

Can Anyone explain this

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class MyExecuterService  {

    private  ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> runnables;
    //private AtomicBoolean execute=AtomicBoolean.true;
    private PoolWorkerThread poolWorkerThreads[];

    public MyExecuterService()
    {}

    public MyExecuterService(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> runnables,PoolWorkerThread poolWorkerThreads1[])
    {
        this.runnables=runnables;
        poolWorkerThreads=poolWorkerThreads1;
    }

    private class PoolWorkerThread extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println(runnables.size()+"runnable"+runnables);
                synchronized (runnables) {

                    if(runnables.size()==0)
                    {
                        try {
                        runnables.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Runnable task=runnables.poll();
                        task.run();
                        //notify();
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    public  MyExecuterService newFixedThreadPool(int i)
    {
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> runnableQueue= new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>();

        PoolWorkerThread [] threads= new PoolWorkerThread[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            threads[j]= new PoolWorkerThread();
            threads[j].start();
        }
        return new MyExecuterService(runnableQueue, threads);
    }

    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        System.out.println(runnables.size());
        synchronized(runnables)
        {
            runnables.add(runnable);
            runnables.notify();
        }
    }
    public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> getRunnables() {
        return runnables;
    }

    public void setRunnables(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> runnables) {
        this.runnables = runnables;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, please indent your code so that we can read and understand your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is due to the data members of `MyExecuterService` not being initialized.

You created the `MyExecuterService` object with parameters in the `new FixedThreadPool(int i)` method, but since this method belongs to `MyExecuterService` itself, so to access this method you must have created a `MyExecuterService` object.
Then only you could access the object.

Now the exception  is occurring due to creating `MyExecuterService` object with the empty parameters constructor so the data members are not being initialized.

Just check through which object you are calling `the newFixedThreadPool(int i)` method and ensure that that object is being created with the parameterized constructor.

By the way, your design of `MyExecuterService` class is kind of hypothetical.

Comment: yes, I was calling the method with the object created by default constructor.
I have corrected it.